# Postgres - Join latest row alongwith complete join

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables `products`, `stock_entries` and `purchase_invoice_items`. I am trying to create a materialized view using these 3 tables. Additionally, I want to join only the latest row of `purchase_invoice_items` as well. Here's the sample of the query:

```
select *, latest_pii.price, latest_pii.id
from products prd
left outer join stock_entries se on se.product_id = prd.id
left outer join purchase_invoice_items pii on pii.id = se.purchase_invoice_item_id
left outer join (
        select id, price
        from purchase_invoice_items
     ) latest_pii ON latest_pii.id = (select max(sq_pii.id) from purchase_invoice_items sq_pii where sq_pii.id = pii.id)
```

But this doesn't give correct results. Here's what output looks like:

```
[
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 350, latest_pii_id: 5, pii_price: 350, pii_id: 5},
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 350, latest_pii_id: 6, pii_price: 350, pii_id: 6},
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 300, latest_pii_id: 9, pii_price: 300, pii_id: 9},
  {id: 2, latest_pii_price: 100, latest_pii_id: 10, pii_price: 100, pii_id: 10},
  {id: 2, latest_pii_price: 150, latest_pii_id: 11, pii_price: 150, pii_id: 11},
]
```

Instead of this, I was expecting output to be like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 300, latest_pii_id: 9, pii_price: 350, pii_id: 5},
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 300, latest_pii_id: 9, pii_price: 350, pii_id: 6},
  {id: 1, latest_pii_price: 300, latest_pii_id: 9, pii_price: 300, pii_id: 9},
  {id: 2, latest_pii_price: 150, latest_pii_id: 11, pii_price: 100, pii_id: 10},
  {id: 2, latest_pii_price: 150, latest_pii_id: 11, pii_price: 150, pii_id: 11},
]
```

I am not able to figure out what am i missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the `where sq_pii.id = pii.id` clause in the max() query guarantees that `pii` and `latest_pii`will be the same row. If you want the most recent row of that table globally (not clear to me from your question if that is your intent), drop that clause.

Comment: order by sq_pii.id desc limit 1 will get the desired results also.  Using Max() can  cause sequential table scan  which can kill preformance

Comment: Do you want a materialized view that generates that JSON output?

Comment: Obviously No. That's just the sample output in human readable format. I have updated the question to include the expected sample output. Kindly check once.

Comment: It would help if you can set up a fiddle with some sample data. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12